# How do i connect to a remote mysql server in .NET?

Tags: .net, mysql, windows, linux, mysql-connector

I am using ubuntu in VMWare. I installed mysql and have it running. I can login with the user root and a password. I have the IP of the VM box. In my code i wrote

using MySql.Data;
return new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("username=root;data source=192.168.100.129,password=xyz");

instead of data source i also tried server. I get the exception message `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

i ran `netstat -an | grep -i mysql` and saw 
`unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     23404    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

so i added port=23404; and tried both `data source` and `server`. No luck. I can indeed ping that address on the virtual machine (i got the address using ifconfig). So Whats my problem and how do i connect? This is the first time i am using this. I always used sqlite in the past.

Comment: `"username=root;data source=192.168.100.129,password=xyz"` is strange: why is the separator a `;`and then a `,` and `data source` with a space?
Did you allow the outside connection to mysql (/etc/hosts.allow)? Can you connect from the machine you develop on with any mysql client?

Comment: Data Source with a space is correct.  But yeah, that needs to be a semicolon between the host address and the word "password".

Comment: I thought it was stupid but copied the comma from a tutorial. I changed it and still no luck. Same message.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a MySQL problem rather than a .NET problem. By default MySQL only listens for connections from localhost (for security reasons). You need to explicitly tell it not to do so. See this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/mysql/switch-mysql-to-listen-on-tcp/ .

Comment: I realized this a minute after i posted. I have done it and i still get the error after i restarted the server.

Comment: Did you try connecting from a MySQL client instead of from .NET?